# how can i place my header to left when orientation change in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to place my header to the left side when the orientation is changed to landscape mode and my whole.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Could you give more details as to what you want to do? Is this for a Tablet or Phone? When you say Header, what do you mean? Could you give some example code as to what you have tried and/or use something like http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

use media queries in CSS to achieve this. Code example :

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* Use CSS here to align header to top */
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
 /* Use CSS here to align header to left */
}
```